# Using a variable as an object key in Django Template Tags

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have two 4 tier objects that I am passing to the django template. I am currently for looping through each tier, and going down a level if it exists. I ended up having key, key2 and key3 that represents the current location in the object while looping. I would like to reference the other object that has the same tiers using those variables, but am having some trouble.

If I was trying to do this in python, it would look like this

`my_object[ key ][ key2 ][ key3 ]`

But in django templates, it doesn't seem I can use brackets, and if I used periods it would think key is the key name, and not look at it as a variable.

If you need more details on my code, let me know. Thanks!

Edit: Here is an example of what my object looks like, and my template code.

```
variable1 = {
    "content": {
        "pages": {
            "view":True,
            "add":True,
            "edit":True,
            "delete":True
        },
        "articles": {
            "view":True,
            "add":True,
            "edit":True,
            "delete":True
        },
        "slideshow": {
            "view":True,
            "edit":True
        },
    },
    "people": {
        "view":True,
        "add":True,
        "edit":True,
        "delete":True,
        "sort-staff":True,
        "sort-riders":True
    }
}
```

variable2 is the same as variable one, with the same keys, but some keys are missing.

Here is what my template looks like to sort through this object.

```
{% for key, value in variable1.items %}
    <strong>{{ key|title }}</strong>
    {% for key2, value2 in value.items %}
        {% if value2.items %}
            <p class="indent">{{ key2|title }}
            {% for key3, value3 in value2.items %}
                <p class="indent"><input type="checkbox" name="form_permission_{{ key }}_{{ key2 }}_{{ key3 }}" {% if variable2[key][key2][key3] %}checked="checked"{% endif %}> {{ key3|title }}</p>
            {% endfor %}
            </p>
        {% else %}
            <p class="indent"><input type="checkbox" name="form_permission_{{ key }}_{{ key2 }}"> {{ key2|title }}</p>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you look at the most indented line, you will see `{% if variable2[key][key2][key3] %}checked="checked"{% endif %}`. You should be able to understand what I'm trying to accomplish with that code.

Comment: can you post what your object looks like and your template code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the sorting and comparing before the data was sent to the template so this question is no longer needed. Feel free to post other options.

Answer (score 0):

That cannot be done this way. Look into writing a template tag or filter for this.

Comment: I was pretty sure this couldn't be done, but it seems like something a lot of people might find themselves needing. My hope was to find something someone already wrote (custom tag or filter) that I can plug in.